# java ArrayList returns wrong result

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to use ArrayList to pop up data in the table

My code is

```
public class Search {
    public String url;
    public String txt;

    public Search(String url, String txt) {
        this.url = url;
        this.txt = txt; 
        }

     public String geturl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void seturl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
     public String gettxt() {
        return txt;
    }
    public void settxt(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

...
Search o1 = new Search(doc.get("uri"),txt);
lst.add(o1);
```

...

Result is `[com.jcasey.IndexImpl$Search@507c0719]` but should be `[https://www.experts-exchange.com, Welcome to Experts Exchange]`

What I'm doing wrong? Please advise

Comment: `I have to use ArrayList ` - and where is ArrayList in your code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how this is displayed..You need to iterate the list and get the properties (for ex : url) and then print them.. printing the whole list directly won't work since you have a list of your own class objects not just string...i can add it to the answer if you want..

Comment: override toString()Method of Search class. Bydefault this method returns the address of your object in memory. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

@Pratyay

Comment: What you see is a reference address to a Java object in the heap memory. I think that you are printing `o1` to the console/view for debugging. The value of `o1` is an reference. When you use `o1` to call a method, that reference is used to find the right object. Since you did not have defined a `toString()` method in your `Search` class, the JVM will display the value instead. Not the content. Thus you get a reference address to your display. Overriding `toString()` allows you to give another value than the reference address.

Comment: @rkosegi The provided code is not complete, but you can see an addition to a collection at the last line: `lst.add(o1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please override the toString() method in your Search class.

```
public String toString(){
return url + ", " + txt;
}
```

Comment: Tank you. Yes, it is working now

Comment: @Nadia please mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

You didn't override `toString()` for `Search` class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return url + ", " + txt;
}
```